# How to access data returned from JSONP GET request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I need to make a cross-domain request and provide cookies/credentials in order to access the other domain. I'm using JSONP in Jquery to accomplish this. My test has been successful insofar as I can see the request return a 200 in the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools.

The problem is that I'm getting an error that says the Callback function was not called. I understand this to mean that the remote server is not responding with a callback function. However, this is expected as the server doesn't implement JSONP and I'm just trying to use JSONP to get data from a domain I don't own/control.

My question is, since I'm getting a 200, is there a way to access the data? Even if I have to do so from within an error function?

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    cache: true,
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 5000,
    url: "https://remote.domain.com/path/search",
     data: 'keyword=ramy-testing',
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(xhr.status);       //displays "200" in alert window
        alert(xhr.statusText);   //displays "success" in alert window
        alert(xhr.responseText); //displays "undefined" in alert window
        alert(thrownError);      //displays "Error: [callback name] was not called"
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done.

The response from the server is not JSONP, it's just JSON object. The callback isn't being called (because it doesn't exist) and the response fails.

Can't get around the Same Origin policy if the remote server doesn't allow it.